# Conversion of polar equations

Tags: polar-coordinates

How would you say have some equation in the polar coordinate system as:
$$r=3\sin3\theta $$

I know how to find the are of one petal of this shape using polar coordinate integration, but say if I convert this to its Cartesian form this exact polar equation using $ x = r \cos \theta$ , $y= r \sin\theta$, then how would I find the area in when it is in the Cartesian form?

Could anyone give me some clear steps, this will really help me understand better. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

As you know we have $$ \sin 3\theta = 3 \sin \theta -4 \sin ^3 \theta $$

Thus your equation in Cartesian coordinates gets a little bit complicated. $$ r = 3 \sin (3\theta ) \implies r^2=3r (3\sin \theta -4\sin ^3 \theta )$$
$$ x^2+y^2=9y -12y \frac {y^2}{x^2+y^2}$$

It is not any easier than polar form.

Comment: Yes thank you I know how to find this in cartesian but how I would i find this area using the cartesian form?

Comment: You have to cut it into parts where $y$ is a function of $x$ and use symmetry for other parts. Good luck

Comment: Could you be nice enough to show me how this is done, I just dont have any examples in the textbook ...

Comment: Check wolfram alpha to solve for y as a function of x

Comment: But how would i know my limits?

Comment: You can get ideas from the polar graph

Comment: May I ask what the limits would be in Cartesian or help me set up the integral in the Cartesian form? I still seem to be stuck.

Comment: Your first half loop starts at $(0,0)$ and stops at $(3\sqrt 3/2,3/2)$

Comment: Thanks for the reply however what I am confused i with what equation do we use to integrate this function, cause I do not know how to express that quadratic of our polar equation, and from what I understand with double integrals:
$$A=\int_{x_1}^{x_2}\int_{y_1}^{y_2}1dydx$$
But shouldnt $y$ be a function of $x?$ But it seems quite hard for me to do that with the case of these quartic polynomials.

Comment: $A=\int_{0}^{3\sqrt3 /3}\int_{y_1}^{x/2}1dydx $ where y_1 is the  polar function in cartesian form.

Comment: I really appreciate this but what I do not get is how can we find $y_1$, as $y_1 $in the Cartesian form you have given me has both $ x$ and $y$ on two sides of the equation, so which do we make $y$ the subject?